# How to create generate Form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have to write a log of codes when open new Windows Form.

Can I make a function to run this command? by call it with "fDeliveryNotation" only

```
Case "Delivery Notation"
                If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of fDeliveryNotation).Any Then
                    For Each f As Form In Application.OpenForms
                        If TypeOf f Is fDeliveryNotation Then
                            f.Activate()
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                Else
                    Dim NewMDIChild As New fDeliveryNotation
                    NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me
                    NewMDIChild.Show()
                    NewMDIChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                End If
```

- Code for open new window when window not exist if exist activate it.

Comment: Could you explain better what is the problem with this code?

Comment: I try to improve reuse ability in my source code by remove repeatedly code to open new form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic function:

```
Public Sub OpenForms(Of T As {New, Form})()
    Dim tForms = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of T)()
    If tForms.Any() Then
        tForms.Select(Function(x) x).First().Activate()
    Else
        Dim NewMDIChild As New T
        NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me
        NewMDIChild.Show()
        NewMDIChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End If
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Public Sub Foo()
   OpenForms(Of fDeliveryNotation)()
   ''OpenForms(Of Application)() Compile Error since Application is not a Form
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
Added constructor constraint for T and create new instance of T instead of hard coded Form